# Why does not this real-time data code work in Google Colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, google-colaboratory, real-time

I have a problem with the following code which is expected to show a 2D graph that is changing every time my text file named "example" is updated. When you run it in Google Colab, nothing shows up while it is running without any error.

Your help would be highly appreciated:)

```
[1] from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')


[2] import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[3] %matplotlib notebook
    plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'jshtml'

[4] fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fig.show()

[5] x, y = [], []
    leng1 = 0
    i = 0

    while True:
         pullData = open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/example.txt', 'r').read()
         leng2 = len(pullData)
         pullData = pullData[leng1:leng2]
         leng1 = leng2
         dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
         for eachLine in dataArray:
             if len(eachLine)>1:
                 xar,yar = eachLine.split(',')
                 x.append(int(xar))
                 y.append(float(yar))

         ax.plot(x, y, color='b')

         fig.canvas.draw()

         ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, i - 50), right=i + 50)
         fig.show()
         plt.pause(0.05)
         i += 1
```

Comment: what happens if you 1) run it in a notebook on your local machine 2) run it all in one cell and 3) run it all in one cell in a notebook on your local machine?

Comment: also, is "example.txt" ever getting updated? if the final isn't changing, i wouldn't expect the plot to change either

Comment: I think you need to mount your drive. Did you?

Comment: Actually, it is properly running in my local machine. My problem is with Google Colab, and  it's the same when I run it in one cell. Also, "example.txt" is updating in another notebook while this code is running. @PaulH

Comment: Yeah, I mount the drive before I run the code. The problem is, it is running without getting any output even a single error:( @AyeshaKhan

Comment: you're not closing the file. that might have something to do with it

Comment: I closed it and tried again, but the same result happened:(@PaulH

Comment: Is `xar` >> `i`? Your x-axis limits might be hiding any changes you are making to the plot.

Comment: Also, %matplotlib notebook does not work on colab.